# How can writing a Review Paper possibly help in the CV of a undergraduate student?

Tags: journals, mathematics, computer-science, research-undergraduate, review-articles

I'm  a student of computer science amd I've written a reseaech review article on Fibonacci Sequence which will be published next month in a math journal. All I wanted to know is how will it help in my academic profile and what affects will it make in my CV?

Comment: Positive effects, as long as it's a well-written review in a decent journal.

Comment: Just a small point about the specifics of the question: as a mathematician, I'd very strongly anticipate that any journal that would publish presumably-well-known (whether or not interesting) facts about Fibonacci numbers would not be what mathematicians would call a "research" journal, but more "expository" or "teaching". As you say, "review". Probably not really "research review". Still, a pleasant accomplishment for an undergrad, and more than many/most accomplish. But do be careful not to err by imagining that this will help much down the road.

Comment: Thanks @paul . I'm well aware about my review paper.  And the objective of writing it was to provide overall history, findings and implications in the field of math and computer science. I'm also convinced for atleast being able to accomplish a review, which I will take as synergy for further independent research. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Any work of quality adds value to your profile. If I refer to your question, even the act of writing a review paper, if performed by the rules of the art, is something that you can show and discuss about.

Addtionnaly, if the work has received some sound academic validation (published in a reputed journal) of course this adds to your resume. It adds sometimes more if the topic of your work is close to your background, which seems to be the case here.

Beware though: it is not common for an undergraduate to be able to write correctly a review paper, esp. on a well-paved topic such as Fibonacci numbers. So, to be blunt, if your paper was accepted almost without review in a local university journal, it might weight less. Or even negatively.

This really depends on who reads your CV: some will be impressed by the: "published in the Mathematical Journal of Mathematics". Some others may have a look at your paper precisely. If they find that the content is of low level, they might have a more negative opinion than if they were not aware of your paper.

Comment: Thank you @Laurent . It is actually written under the supervision of my course instructor who is a Professor of Mathematics. So I'm quite confident that the contents are precisely reffered from core research papers on Fibonacci Sequences.

Comment: Excellent. Do not hesitate to post it when published, I love the topic

Comment: l. Ofcourse I will...

Answer (score 2):

ANYTHING you do as an undergrad helps your professional trajectory. Even if it's just running subjects in experiences or gathering articles for a professor. You get to add that project to your CV, you get the experience, and you get a letter of recommendation (if you do a good job of course). Any writing you do is seen as as a super plus and writing independently would be super super plus. At your level, people are looking to see that you can work and get things done, not that you have the most original ideas (those help, too, but aren't as essential as they are for your profs).

So if the question is "write a review paper v. some other kind of paper" I'd assert that you get a main effect of either and the difference between the two types isn't much. However, writing a review paper will greatly expand your knowledge of the field, which helps you in a lot of ways, and will show that you have pretty sophisticated understanding of a topic for a UG.

Computer science isn't my field (statistics and social science), but at your level people want to see you can do academic work (at least with an advisor, even better independently).

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a kind advice. I'll always keep your words in my mind

Comment: Good luck with it. Stick with it. Publishing academic papers takes a lot of time (both getting it out and waiting while it's out). You may even end up publishing other things while waiting for this one :)